# where clause matching 2 rows in the same table to get results

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a search query that i need to modify and adapt into a custom profile system we have, that system use the following table:

```
  profile_key | profile_value        | user_id
       1      |    test1             |  10
       2      |    test2             |  10
       3      |    ["test3","test4"] |  10
```

i need to add to the where clause something that would match all the rows (depending of what the user defined in the search form) to get the user_id, something like:

```
 select user_id from table where (profile_key = 1 && profile_value regexp 'test1') && (profile_key = 3 && profile_value regexp 'test4')
```

i need to get all the user_id IF it matched all the defined profile_key and the regexp.

any idea how i can accomplish this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profiles WHERE profile_key = 1 
    AND profile_value regexp 'test1' AND profiles.user_id = users.user_id)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profiles WHERE profile_key = 3 
    AND profile_value regexp 'test4' AND profiles.user_id = users.user_id)
```

You could also accomplish this with an `INNER JOIN`, once for each row you want to match:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN profiles p1 ON users.user_id = p1.user_id
INNER JOIN profiles p2 ON users.user_id = p2.user_id
WHERE p1.profile_key = 1 AND p1.profile_value regexp 'test1'
AND p2.profile_key = 3 AND p2.profile_value regexp 'test4'
```

Comment: what you posted was not exactly what i needed but the EXIST function solved my problem `select user_id from table where exists(select user_id from table upv where upv.profile_key_id='4' && upv.profile_value regexp "aaaa" ) && exists(select user_id from table upv where upv.profile_key_id='1' && upv.profile_value regexp "shadow" )` thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that `profile_key` should be `1` and `3`. This is impossible.

You need to use an `OR`, not `AND`.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM   table 
WHERE  ( profile_key = 1 && profile_value REGEXP 'test1' ) OR ( 
       profile_key = 3 && profile_value REGEXP 'test4' )
```

Comment: i would not be asking if it would be easy :P that is not an option, i need to know that an user_id has those 2 rows defined

Answer (score 0):

What about using an 'IN', something like this

```
select user_id 
from table 
where (profile_key = 1 && 'test1' IN profile_value) 
    && (profile_key = 3 && 'test4' IN profile_value )
```